# Custom css on bootstrap navbar not displaying correct

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On my bootstrap navbar when the navbar is in desktop mode it should show my border-top css

But for some reason it shows my border-left css It should only show border-left when mobile 768px and under.

Question: How can I make sure when the navbar is shows the correct border for when it is in mobile or desktop

Codepen [Example](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/YWRRkv)

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}
hr {
  border-top: 10px solid #444444;
  position: fixed;
}
.page-wrapper {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.custom-nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #333333;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-brand {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.home {
  border-top: 2px solid #AC3931;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.home:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.home:focus {
  background-color: #AC3931;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.forum {
  border-top: 2px solid #F6AE2D;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.forum:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.forum:focus {
  background-color: #F6AE2D;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.blog {
  border-top: 2px solid #3B910D;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.blog:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.blog:focus {
  background-color: #3B910D;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.examples {
  border-top: 2px solid #2868B7;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.examples:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.examples:focus {
  background-color: #2868B7;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.home {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #AC3931;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.forum {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #F6AE2D;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.blog {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #3B910D;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.examples {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #2868B7;
}
.page {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  /*box-shadow: 6px 6px 0px #989898, 12px 12px 0px #6B6666;*/
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.module {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.module .module-info {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'source code pro';
}
.module .module-title {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-wrapper">

<div class="container">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse custom-nav">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li ><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class="forum" href="#">Forum</a></li>
         <li><a class="blog" href="#">Blog</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle examples" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CodeIgniter Examples <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </nav>
</div><!-- /.container-->

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `@media rule` and then put all related CSS code for particular mobile with screen size inside it, like below:

```css
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.examples {
 border-top: 2px solid #2868B7;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.examples:hover, 
.custom-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.examples:focus {
    background-color: #2868B7;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
  .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.home {
      border-top: none;
   border-left: 2px solid #AC3931;
  }

  .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.forum {
   border-top: none;
   border-left: 2px solid #F6AE2D;
   }

  .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.blog {
   border-top: none;
   border-left: 2px solid #3B910D;
  }

  .custom-nav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a.examples {
   border-top: none;
   border-left: 2px solid #2868B7;
  }
}
```

For more detail check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should add you border-left css in a media query with max-width:768px.

```
@media (max-width:768px){
/*put your css here*/
}
```

It will apll your css only on screen width of 768px and below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to set different breakpoints and change the style for each break point. Something like the following:

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
```